# Rotate or flip preview in Android Camera2 API

Tags: android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to rotate and/or flip the preview being displayed using the Camera2 API.

I tried setting the `JPEG_ORIENTATION` on the `previewRequestbuilder` to rotate the preview but that did not have any effect.

What other methods are available to rotate the preview?

In Camera1, this was achieved via `setdisplayorientation`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct control for this - for SurfaceViews and TextureViews, the correct rotation is baked in by the API.  For a pure SurfaceTexture, the getTransform() call includes the correct rotation.

If you want your own custom flip or rotation, you'll need to do your own GL rendering with a SurfaceTexture and a GLSurfaceView or equivalent.

Comment: Thankyou @Eddy talvala . I was able to rotate the preview with Matrix.postrotate. However, the image is cropped from what I would see when it is in landscape.

Comment: Well, if you just rotate a landscape image in a landscape View by 90 degrees, it won't fit.  You'll have to shrink it too, if you want to see all of it.